# php login / register to txt data file

Tags: php

I have a simple project. In this project I want to create a login page. 
Users can insert a username, a name and a password and register with the system. If a user is already registered, the system shall send an error and if the password is incorrect the system shall send an error, too.

The data is getting saved to `users.txt` file at 3 lines: lin1=name, line2=user and line3=pass

My code does not work and I have problems with the registration.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body align="center">
    <form method="post">
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        Name:<input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
        Username:<input type="text" name="username"><br><br>
        Password:<input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>

    <?php
        if ($_POST['name'] != null && $_POST['username'] != null && $_POST['password'] != null){
            $a = 0;
            $file = fopen('users.txt', 'r');
            while (!feof($file)) {
                $nam = fgets($file);
                $user = fgets($file);
                $pass = fgets($file);
                if ($nam === $_POST['name'] && $user === $_POST['username'] && $pass === $_POST['password']) {
                    echo "successfull login !";
                    $a = 1;
                    fclose($file);
                }
                else if ($user === $_POST['username'] && $nam !== $_POST['name'] && $pass !== $_POST['password']) {
                    $a = 2;
                    echo "this username already is token!";
                    fclose($file);
                }
                else if ($user === $_POST['username'] && $nam === $_POST['name'] && $pass !== $_POST['password']) {
                    echo "password is incorect";
                    $a = 3;
                    fclose($file);
                }
            }
            fclose($file);
            if ($a == 0){
                $file = fopen('users.txt', 'a+');
                fputs($file, $_POST['name']);
                fputs($file, "\r\n");
                fputs($file, $_POST['username']);
                fputs($file, "\r\n");
                fputs($file, $_POST['password']);
                fputs($file, "\r\n");
                fclose($file);
                echo "register is successfull";
                echo $nam;
                echo $user;
                echo $pass;
            }
        }
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: I guess he is not able to avoid duplicate registration. @JayBlanchard

Comment: He's not looping through the file to test for the names and passwords. file based authentication seems like a bad plan to me @FakhruddinUjjainwala

Comment: Yes exactly. Why not use database for storing data?